# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from my regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have this Regex, but when try using it in mysql query statement, i got SQL Error [1139] [42000]: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

```
^((?!\.).)*.id$
```

after digging from Stackoverflow, i got information that mysql regex doesn't support operator with question mark (?).

How to make it works in mysql?

my goal is to filter domain name with .ID TLD's.
When i'm using "end-with" method, i got problem with domains that ended with .id but not exactly .id, it can be .web.id , .co.id , .or.id etc.

Comment: MySQL, before 8.0, does not understand the `?` operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only strings with ".id" at the end and no "." before that but at lease one character before the ".", you can try to match the whole string and use a negated character class:

```
...
nmuloc REGEXP '^[^\.]+\.id$'
...
```

If an empty string before the "." is OK you can change the `+` quantifier to `*`.

Comment: Its Working, Thank you very much